# How To iterate the Start Date to end Date in java

Tags: java

Hi I need to find the In between Dates for java the example for

StartDate=`2017-01-28` and

EndDate=`2017-02-0`3

I expect the output:

```
2017-01-28 
2017-01-29 
2017-01-30 
2017-01-31 
2017-02-01 
2017-02-02 
2017-02-03
```

Please help me thank You..

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: I tried this type but not working for (LocalDate date = fromDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1))
  {
      
  }

Comment: N, it is already being asked many times before and answered in Stackoverflow.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d");
  Date d1 = null;
  Date d2 = null;
  try {
         d1 = format.parse(fromDate);
         d2 = format.parse(endDate);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: So is the question; how to I parse LocalDate, or is it how to convert a Date into a LocalDate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Java Calendar to achieve this :

```
Date start = new Date();
Date end = new Date();

Calendar cStart = Calendar.getInstance(); cStart.setTime(start);
Calendar cEnd = Calendar.getInstance(); cEnd.setTime(end);

while (cStart.before(cEnd)) {

    //add one day to date
    cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer in Java 8 using package `java.time`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-01-28");
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-02-03");
LocalDate d = startDate;

while (d.isBefore(endDate) || d.equals(endDate)) {
  builder.append(d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)).append(" ");
  d = d.plusDays(1);
}

// "2017-01-28 2017-01-29 2017-01-30 2017-01-31 2017-02-01 2017-02-02 2017-02-03"
String result = builder.toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this (using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/))

```
for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date =    date.plusDays(1))
{
   ...
}
```

I would thoroughly recommend using Joda Time over the built-in Date/Calendar classes.